# PHP when and when not to use a return statement inside a user defined function

Tags: php, function

I was wondering if a user defined function will always needs a return() statement and if not when is a return() statement not required?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: what is with the negative rating?

Comment: Because its not really a question, commonly known and well documented.

Comment: Its still a valid question not every one knows everything about php or do they?

Comment: Not entirely in my opinion. If that's the case, that person should learn himself how to use the documentation to solve his problem, or purchase a proper book about the subject. Even after you master the language you will face problems and questions you dont have the answer for, but you'd have to use the resources available to solve your problem.

Comment: still not a valid reason for a negative.

Comment: If you want your function to return `NULL` it's not required to write a `return` statement (w/o `()` please!). For every other return type/value, you need a `return` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. It's only required if you want to use it.

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php:

> Values are returned by using the **optional** return statement.

Comment: will the functions results still be displayed like `hello world` if i don't use the return statement?

Comment: Well, that depends on the content of the function and how it's implemented. The function itself can do an `echo "hello world";`, for instance - that doesn't need a return value. But if you `echo` the return value, you need to `return "hello world"`.

Comment: your answer kind of confused me can you give an example if possible?

Comment: Please read the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php or try some tutorials.

Comment: Probably worth to point out that functions that not explicitly return something will return `NULL`. Often documented as `@return void` in docblock comments / API docs.

Answer (score 1):

If your function doesn't need to return anything, then it doesn't have to.

Saying that, I tend to return a boolean as to whether the function completed its job or not. Other times, I just let it move to its next job.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally up to you. If you want your function to return some result to use elsewhere, then you should have it return something. Otherwise, if your function does something, but you don't need a result, then don't have it return anything.

**It is your choice.**